# Manually created global.asax.cs file doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax, vs-web-site-project

I have Web Site Project and I have started developing api (atleast trying).

Problem is with creating `Global.asax` file. Since this is `Web Site Project`, when I create `Global Application Class` it creates only `Global.asax` without `Global.asax.cs`

After some research, I have found out I need to do it manually so I created `Global.asax.cs` file and it automatically set it under my already created `Global.asax` which I think is good.

Problem is I think that my code inside `Global.asax.cs` isn't running. I tried putting breakpoint inside `Global.asax - Application_Start function` and it stops there (which mean it is working), but when I do the same at `Global.asax.cs`, it doesn't stop.

I have tried adding `<%@ Application Language="C#" Inhertis="Global.asax"%>` inside `Global.asax` but what I get is `Could not load type 'Global.asax'`

What should I do?

EDIT:

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
/// 
public class Global
{
    public Global()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a web site project to test this out (wasn't sure on details since I don't work with web site projects much). I have `Global.asax.cs` class within an `App_Code` folder (location recommended by VS). With the following setup, I'm hitting breakpoints inside Global.asax.cs:

Your Global.asax should read something like this, assuming that the class name in `Global.asax.cs` is `Global` (you could make that custom):

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="App_Code\Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global" %>
```

Importantly, your class `Global` must inherit from `System.Web.HttpApplication`:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public Global()
    {
    }

    protected void Application_Start() 
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("In application start");
    } 
}
```

Comment: It is Web Site Project, it doesn't have namespace or am I wrong?

Comment: Tbh, I'm not sure. You may not need the namespace - but the point is, `Inherits` should definitely not include `.asax`. Does `Inherits="Global"` work?

Comment: `<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Global"%>` I have this and it says `Could not load type 'Global'`

Comment: Inside `Global.asax.cs`, what is the class name that inherits from System.Web.HttpApplication?

Comment: See edits, I created a web site project & am able to hit global.asax.cs breakpoints. Obviously if your global.asax.cs is not within the `App_Code` folder, exclude that from the `Codebehind` path. This is with a manually-created `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: In my Global class I do not have `: System.Web.HttpApplication` and for some reason I cannot add it.